# ASP.NET CORE Dropdown List Validation

Tags: asp.net-core-mvc

I am using `ViewBag` to populate dropdown list in my razor view page in ASP.NET Core MVC form. I tried to set up an initial value, ie. `Text="Select"`, `Value=""`, so if user selects the default value, the form will show error message. I tried to set default value in model class but the validation does not work when user skips dropdown list. Please advise.

Model class:

```
myClass
{
    [StringLength(250)]
    [Required]
    public string lunch { get; set; } = String.Empty;
}
```

Controller:

```
public IActionResult Create()
{
    List<SelectListItem> lunch = new List<SelectListItem>
            {
                new SelectListItem{Value="No lunch", Text="No lunch"},
                new SelectListItem{Value="Turkey Sandwitch", Text="Turkey Sandwitch"}
                new SelectListItem{Value="Vegie Sandwitch", Text="Vegie Sandwitch"}
            };

    lunch.Insert(0, new SelectListItem { Value = String.Empty, Text = "Select" });

    ViewBag.lunch = lunch;

    return View();
}
```

View:

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label asp-for="lunch" class="control-label"></label>
    @Html.DropDownList("lunch",  new SelectList(ViewBag.lunch,"Value","Text"))       
    <span asp-validation-for="lunch" class="text-danger"  ></span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out myself by changing the razor view page code as below:

```
<select asp-for="lunch" asp-items="@(new SelectList(ViewBag.lunches, "Value","Text"))" >
  <option disabled selected>--- SELECT ---</option>
</select>
```

Controller:

```
List<SelectListItem> lunches = new List<SelectListItem>
            {
                new SelectListItem{Value="No lunch", Text="No lunch"},
                new SelectListItem{Value="Turkey Sandwitch", Text="Turkey Sandwitch"}
                new SelectListItem{Value="Vegie Sandwitch", Text="Vegie Sandwitch"}
            };
ViewBag.lunches= lunches;
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to skip the model validation when you do not select anything, I suggest you can change `[Required]` to `[BindRequired]`.

`[Required]` attribute means you must contain the field with value, `[BindRequired]` attribute means you must contain the field.

If you also use ASP.NET 6, remember to add `?` to your property. Otherwise it will default make the property Required validation although you do not use `[Required]` attribute.

```
public class myClass
{
    [StringLength(250)]
    [BindRequired]
    public string? lunch { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. I want to check if user has selected lunch option. Right now the validation does not fire when the dropdown list has the  default value "Select".

Comment: Hi @user788448, not clear with what you said now.  You do not want skip the validation when user does not select?

Comment: Hi Rena, you are correct. The dropdown list has default value "Select", I want to validate when user selects anything but "Select". Thanks.

Comment: Hi @Rena, I meant you are correct that I don't want user to skip the lunch dropdown validation. The dropdown has initial value "Select"  which causes the validation doesn't work. Sorry for the confusion.